# Where to find E-mini S&P options price data or chart?

Tags: options, market-data, futures

ES futures price data is easy to find, e.g. on [Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=ESH16.CME%20Interactive#%7B%22range%22:%221d%22,%22allowChartStacking%22:true%7D) or with a free NinjaTrader demo account. I'm looking for the same for options on that futures contract.

The best I could find is the current price, e.g. at [BarChart](http://www.barchart.com/commodityfutures/E-Mini_S%26P_500_Futures/options/ES?view=split) and 
[CommodityCharts](http://www.commoditycharts.com/options/E-Mini_S&P_500/ESH16/&mode=i&view=), but I'd like to see the price movement, at least over the last day. It doesn't need to be very precise - something like the Yahoo chart would be just fine.

Comment: Options can be far less liquid than the futures, the intraday graphs would look quite jumpy and full of gaps, that is probably why they don't publish them.

Comment: Sure, not necessarily intraday, but can I see the price history over (at least) the last few days somewhere? The sites I found only show the current prices.

Comment: Also, those site don't seem to have the weekly options.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! **Interactive Brokers** provides a [free trial](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1286) account, which allows you to use their Web Trader platform (or TWS, the desktop application) to see (delayed) price data for all kinds of instruments, including futures options, both weekly and monthly.